# On hover Drop down menu disappearing

Tags: html, css

I have created a on hover dropdown and used a form as is its content but when ever I try to hover down into the contents the button disappers.How can I fix this ? this seems to be working perfectly in windows devices however I am using safari

```css
 .dropbtn {
      background-color: #000000;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      float: right;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
      
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      z-index: 100000;
      
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
      color: orangered;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="width">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Web Page color</button>
          <form action="">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <label for="color">Page Color:</label>
              <input
                type="color"
                name="color"
                id="color"
                value="#fde6ee"
                onchange="changecolor()"
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Does the behavior occur in other browsers *on your Mac*, or just Safari? It could simply be a bug in the latest version of Safari